# Passing workbook object to a variable

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have this code and it gives me a Compile error: Expected Function or Variable.
How do i code this properly.

```
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim FiletoOpen

FiletoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Text Files (*.csv), *.csv", MultiSelect:=False)

Set csv_wb = Workbooks.OpenText(Filename:=FiletoOpen, startRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
        , Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
        Array(2, 1), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), _
        Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1)))

End Sub
```

If I use `Set csv_wb = Workbooks.Open (FiletoOpen)` it works fine.
But there are specific fields in the file that I need to be in `Text` format.
So I cannot use this. But when I use the above, it gives me the error.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `wb` but using `csv_WB` Try This.

**UNTESTED**

```
Sub test()
    Dim csv_WB As Workbook
    Dim FiletoOpen

    FiletoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Text Files (*.csv), *.csv", MultiSelect:=False)

    If FiletoOpen = False Then Exit Sub

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=FiletoOpen, startRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
                xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
                , Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), _
                Array(2, 1), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), _
                Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1))

    Set csv_WB = ActiveWorkbook

End Sub
```

Comment: @sid that was a typo. this code is originally a part of bigger code. I just transferred it to isolate this problem. i edited the post already. thanks.

Comment: @pnuts: Thanks I was about to add the suggestion about OE to my above post when I noticed L42's post that he is aware of it :)